# How can I add an autoincrementing ID field to a table in SQL-SERVER starting from X

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL server right now, and I want to add the column PART_NO to it. It needs to be auto incremented (1,2,3 etc) starting from the number 107.

How can I do something like this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using [`alter table add`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx) to add a column with the identity(autoincrementing) property using [`identity()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx) you can set the seed value for the first row, and the increment number. `identity(seed,increment)`.

```
alter table [tbl] add part_no int identity (107,1) not null;
```

Comment: @rohanharrison If an answer solves your problem, you should mark it as accepted so that other people will know that the problem is solved.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Well there is a time limit on how fast you can accept an answer, so I was waiting for that. No need to jump the gun.

Comment: @rohanharrison I'm well aware of the time limit, however when I wrote my comment that time limit was long over... I'm just used to see a lot of questions where no answer doesn't get accepted even though the OP left a comment "it works", just like you did. No offence, but I didn't have any reason to think this is not the case here.

Answer (score -1):

Use the following command

```
Alter table tablename add columnname int identity <starting number,incremented by> not null;
```